# Separate datas throgh the filter on page

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI and need your advice.

The situation is the following. I have a table that has a unique ID and the number of people corresponding to the unique id, separated by gender.

| ID | woman | man |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 9 |

I, through the filter on page, select a specific id.

How can I display a row like ID / Gender in a new table

I tried to using such code as:
ROW (18-59 = ROW("Age", "18-59", "Female", SUM('One Site'[Women (18-59)]), "Male", SUM('One Site'[Men (18-59)]))
But this code sumarize all datas, this is what i need. I need to see datas only from one row

| ID | woman | man |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 7 | 2 |